# Simple division answer without decimal places

Tags: vb6

I want to create this simple division program.But the problem is that the divisors should not be such that the answer is in decimal places, how do I put the check.Guidance would be appreciated.

```
 Option Explicit
  Dim fiCScore As Integer
  Dim fiWScore As Integer
  Dim fsUsername As String
  Dim fiMax1 As Integer
  Dim fiMax2 As Integer
  Dim liWans As Integer

  Private Sub Form_Load()

 lstCorrect.Clear
 lstWrong.Clear
 fiCScore = 0
 fiWScore = 0
 Randomize
 End Sub

 Private Sub cmdAskQuestion_Click()
 Ask_Question
 End Sub

 Public Sub Ask_Question()
 Dim liOperand1 As Integer
 Dim liOperand2 As Integer
 Dim liResult As Integer
 Dim fbAnswer As Boolean

 Dim liEqua1 As Integer
 Dim liEqua2 As Integer
 Dim lsSign As String


 ' Number Generation '
 fiMax1 = 20
 fiMax2 = 20

 liEqua1 = Int(fiMax1 * Rnd) + 1
 liEqua2 = Int(fiMax2 * Rnd) + 1
 liOperand1 = liEqua1
 liOperand2 = liEqua2

 ' Sign Option Select '
      '
 ' Division '
 If optDivide = True Then
    lsSign = " /  "
    If liEqua1 < liEqua2 Then
        liOperand1 = liEqua2
        liOperand2 = liEqua1
    End If
    '**Problem Point**
    liResult = liOperand1 / liOperand2 'liOperand1 / liOperand2 should not be such that answer (liResult) is in decimal places
 End If


 QuestionAsk:
 liWans = Val(InputBox("What is " & liOperand1 & lsSign & _
        liOperand2 & " ?"))

 End_Time

 ' If Wans_Validate = False Then                                       

              '
 ' MsgBox "Please enter numbers only.", vbCritical, "ERROR" '
 ' GoTo QuestionAsk                                                    

                        '
 ' End If                                                              

                                         '
 ' Answer Checking  Correct or Wrong                                   

         '
 If liWans = liResult Then
    MsgBox ("Correct Answer!")
    fbAnswer = True
 Else
    MsgBox ("Incorrect Answer! " _
            & liOperand1 & lsSign & liOperand2 & " = " & liResult)
 End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion 1 (avoiding implicit casting):

```
 If CDbl(liResult) = CDbl(liOperand1 / liOperand2) Then
   MsgBox "result is an integer"
 Else
   MsgBox "result is not an integer"
 End If
```

Suggestion 2 (based on the answer by @Ryan):

```
 If (liOperand1 / liOperand2) = (liOperand1 \ liOperand2) Then
   MsgBox "result is an integer"
 Else
   MsgBox "result is not an integer"
 End If
```

Comment: Thanks the second suggestion suited me the best as in the first 4.25 is also an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only want to return the integer portion (quotient) of the answer.  To do this you can use '\' instead of '/'.

```
 Dim k As Integer
 k = 23 \ 5 ' sets k to 4.
```

Comment: Not exactly.I did not want that the answer ever is decimal.Never the divisors be such that answer is in decimal places.